# PouchDB CRUD pattern using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, pouchdb

I wrote an Electron application in React which uses PouchDB locally synced with a remote CouchDB. I use Redux for state management and want to find out what is the best practice for CRUD?

One requirement I have (and this is why I am unsure of the best pattern to use) is the application needs to update when someone else changes something remotely.

With this in mind I have tried 2 patterns so far.

1. Listen to [changes](https://pouchdb.com/guides/changes.html) with the `DB.changes()` which will fetch all data on every change (throttled with middle-ware but could do with `redux-saga`). This method resulted in a noticeably long turn around between user interaction and fresh data loaded into app because the user would update, then the "Update successful" message is shown and eventually the "Data updated" message is shown. Of course there are actions being dispatched at each of these points which is effecting the UI rendering and adding to bad user experience. the `DB.changes()` method can return the changed document which I do not specify in this method

   ```
   DBChanges = DBChanges.changes({
     since: 'now',
     live: true,
     include_docs: false
   }).on('change', change => {
     // handle change
     fetchAllDocs().then(setAllDocsInApplication)
   });
   ```
2. Listen to [changes](https://pouchdb.com/guides/changes.html) with the `DB.changes()` including the changed doc. These changes can be remote or from the user interaction within the app. On every change, look at the returned doc and mutate the application state depending on the change. This makes the whole cycle time much smaller BUT this feels like a bad pattern as I am mutating the fetched data.

   ```
   DBChanges = DBChanges.changes({
     since: 'now',
     live: true,
     include_docs: true
   }).on('change', change => {
     // handle change
     if(change.deleted)
       handleRemove(change.doc)
     if(change..doc._rev.split("-")[0] === "1")
       handleNewDoc(change.doc)
     handleUpdateDoc(change.doc)
   });
   ```

So what I want to know is what is the best pattern for CRUD with a live updates?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer boils down to this:

Do you need to build the entire app state from the docs from scratch for every change – or can you determine the kind of action that is required from the incoming changes?

Think about your data flow when the user interacts with the app. You probably init the app like so:

```
allDocs → derive initial AppState → render in React
```

So what happens, if for example the user creates a new Item, do you?

```
putDoc → allDocs → derive entire AppState → render in React
```

or do you:

```
putDoc → trigger Redux action that modifies AppState → render in React
```

If you go with the latter (I assume so), your changes handler basically looks the same. There's incoming changes and the question is: Can you determine the required Redux action from the incoming change? The change gives you:

- type of document (hopefully you have this as a property)
- wether it was deleted or not

So, when a change comes in, in your handler, you'd do:

```
changeHandler → trigger Redux action that modifies AppState → render in React
```

Which is option 2.

Option 1 looks like this:

```
changeHandler → allDocs → derive initial AppState → render in React
```

Option 1 has a major downside: If your app goes offline for a few weeks and the remote DB gets a lot of changes (for example, because the Electron app is run on another computer), going back online will result in A LOT of changes being downloaded and every single change will trigger your `fetchAllDocs()` call.

> BUT this feels like a bad pattern as I am mutating the fetched data.

Why? You don't mutate the fetched data (I assume you meant the initial allDocs). The initial allDocs helped only to derive the AppState, you're working with in Redux and React. You probably don't use the stuff in allDocs as your AppState, do you?

Comment: thanks for the response. I am currenlty using option 2 where initially I do just send the entire allDocs (because I use pouch-find plugin so no need for any derivation) to the redux store. I am finding I run into conflict issues a lot more when routing to newly created docs and that is also part of my pattern question I guess - if you add routing into the mix, does the pattern need to change? I currently pass callbacks to my CUD operations that call the 'push("/...")' when complete